# Sim800L not working

Tags: power

I have been trying to set up the SIM800L. The LED is not blinking...

I am using the LM2596 to convert from 5V to 4.3V (I did try with 3.7 <= Vout <=4.3 V) to power the module. With a 5V/2A power supply nothing works aswell.

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried connecting it to an Arduino at any point?

Comment: is the LED supposed to blink?

Comment: Yes, I did connect to test AT commands. The LED should blink since I am powering the module.

Comment: have you checked the power supply voltage at the SIM800L module power pins?

Comment: the soldering job on the module pins looks questionable .... please provide a clear closeup of the module

Comment: I did check for continuity with a multimeter and the solder joints although not great, they conduct. I have at the module 4.2/4.3 V.

Comment: According to [this site](https://nettigo.eu/products/sim800l-gsm-grps-module-spring-antenna) if you give more than 2.8V on the SIM800L **you will kill the module**.